# How to load ini.vim after all plugins in neovim?

Tags: neovim

Code in init.vim does not work as expected until I run

```
source init.vim
```

Looks like some of it is overwritten by other plugins. I did not find anything like .vim/after.

Plugins are managed using vundle.

What is the proper way to execute custom configuration after all plugins or other built in configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved with this hack.

```
alias nvim='nvim  -c "source .config/nvim/init.vim"'
```

I am sure there are better way to do it. Or something else I am doing wrong.